# Jupyter Notbooks not launching

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, anaconda

I'm running Python 3.8 (Anaconda) on Windows 10 and have previously not had any issues launching Jupyter Notebooks. Today that changed: When I tried to launch it from the Anaconda Navigator, it suggested that it launched it but didn't open anything in my default browser (Chrome), so nothing really happened. Also, not terminal prompt was launched. When I tried launching it from the command line, typing both `jupyter notebook` and `jupyter-notebook` it launches the notbook but only in the background (ie. it provides a link that I need to copy into my browser). I find this quite strange and am trying to understand what's going on. My hunch is that it's some kind of Windows related issue but I'd like to know what issue.

So my question is what can explain this behaviour? And assuming that this is related to some strange Windows issue, I'd be keen to find out what it is.

I replicated the exact steps I used to always launch it (which worked), so this shouldn't be anything to do with the setup.

Cheers!

Comment: I am guessing of two possibilities: 1) `C:\Users\[UserName]\.jupyter\.jupyter_notebook_config.py`, and there is an option called `c.NotebookApp.open_browser`. If it is `TRUE`, then your computer will automatically open the default browser. 2) Another is you may not have a default browser now for some unkown reasons, which can be checked in `Start menu->Setting->Default application->Web browser`.

Comment: Thanks for that, the default browser was set to the AVG secure browser. I changed that to Chrome and it worked. It's still strange that it didn't open a browser tab with the AVG secure browser though (which it did previously), but I guess that's one of those Windows issues where things get stuck. Thanks anyway!